# Pasar valor get a un Select

Tags: php, html, select

me gustaria que si por GET traigo unos datos para unos selects.

Como puedo hacer que si traigo valores marcar el seleccionado en el select.

Yo traigo este valor en la barra:

> ver-inmuebles.php?tipo=1&poblaciones=198&contrato=1

Y este es el select donde hay que poner el valor que traiga:

```
<select class="ui fluid dropdown tipo-viv" id="tipo-vivienda"  name="tipoInmueble" style="border:none;">
 <option value="">Todos</option>
 <?php
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos");
   foreach ($results as $tipos){
  ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $tipos['id_tipo'] ?>"><?php echo $tipos['tipo'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Estos selects que tengo ahí, según seleccione ya me filtra resultados.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Traes estos valores dices: `tipo=1&poblaciones=198&contrato=1` ¿y luego? ¿cómo los lees? ¿qué relación tienen con la consulta `SELECT * FROM tipos` que muestras? ¿Qué significa: *Y este es el select donde hay que poner el valor que traiga*?  ¿Qué significa *Estos selects que tengo ahí, según seleccione ya me filtra resultados*?  Aplica el [método de patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Método_de_depuración_del_patito_de_goma) para explicarnos el problema. Te ayudará a ti y a nosotros. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del foreach puedes poner un if en donde compruebes el valor de get que se obtiene de la consulta a la base de datos, si son iguales, imprimes el atributo selected en la etiqueta option que estas imprimiendo.

te quedará algo asi:

```
<select class="ui fluid dropdown tipo-viv" id="tipo-vivienda"  name="tipoInmueble" style="border:none;">
 <option value="">Todos</option>
 <?php
   $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tipos");
   foreach ($results as $tipos){

  ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $tipos['id_tipo'] ?>"   if($_GET['tipo']==$tipos['id_tipo']){
        echo 'selected';
       }><?php echo $tipos['tipo'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Con eso, tomaras el dato enviado pro get, lo compararas con el id_tipo obtenido en cada iteración y cuando haya coincidencias lo marcara como seleccionado automáticamente.
Saludos y espero que te sirva!

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario, si que funciona pero como hago para que actue el onchangue, solo se queda seleccionado pero no detecta ningún cambio @Sergio Sepúlveda

Comment: Con este método el archivo realiza la verificación al momento de cargar la pagina.
Creo que deberías dejar mas detalles para entender tu pregunta. Por que es información que no mencionas arriba y no se bien a que te refieres.

Saludos!

Comment: Pues por el motivo que sea no me filtra